# facebook authentication using laravel 5.1 socialite

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

hello im using localhost so i have recently switched to laravel 5.1 and im trying to use 'socialite' it provides so i have updated my `config` , `services` and the `.env` files so in my routes i also added these codes

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
 });
 Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
 Route::get('auth/facebook/callback','Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
Route::get('home', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => function(){
return view('home');
}));
```

then in my AuthController i have these codes
[image]

in my view the button 'login with facebook' has the `href` of `auth/facebook` but what happens is facebook is giving me an error saying
[image]

note: i also made my facebook app live in the facebook developers
i also added this on my domain but also have a warning
[image]

im still confused on where my error is. any idea what im doing wrong? thanks for advices.

Comment: Add App Domains on your Facebook app setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your site url value into **Site URL** field. Update it and check.

[image]

This should be work for you.

Comment: hi thanks for this! it actually did the job although i had error sayung `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem` but i fixed it by adding a cacert.pem file in my php.ini. Thanks a lot!