# Facebook callback url not valid laravel

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-5, callback, laravel-socialite

I'm using **Socialite** plugin for login with facebook.

When I create application on facebook and when I put this callback url `http://localhost:8080/code/example/public/facebook-login-callback`

> **error**
>
> If you wish to change your callback URL your new URL must use SSL and start with https.

Any ideas?

Comment: you must see this answer first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711934/facebook-authentication-using-laravel-5-1-socialite

Answer (score 1):

Check *App Domain* and *Site URL* value in your facebook app. May be this is your solution.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite straight forward there: Your callback URL needs to use SSL (means (amongst other things): it must start with "https").

Comment: now it gives me error Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.